# Can a cfshedule create a new 'file' everytime it runs?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a cfshedule that runs when a submit button is click, this button will probably be click once a month. After its click it creates the new file

```
<cfoutput>
<h2>Newsletters (months) </h2>
<p>
<a href="cse_execoffice_newsletter.cfm">Newsletter</a><br>


</p>
</cfoutput>
```

This works for right now, but the problem will be when the button is click again, it will overwrite the file cse_exeoffice_newsletter with the new data from that month( this file does no update to the database , just gets data). How can I get it that for every time its click it will generate a new file and not overwrite the last one?

Comment: Can not you create file names dynamically by appending now() to the file name?

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean? can you give me a example online?

Comment: Where's your code that's creating the file?

Comment: So, you want to dynamically generate a dynamic file? Seems like it would be easier to simply write `cse_execoffice_newletters.cfm` in such a way that it can pull in whatever content is desired based off other variables.

Comment: Not related to your question, but the combination of submitting a form and cfschedule is very odd.  Given all your other questions, you might be doing something unwise here.

Comment: @danbracuk, I do feel im doing it the hard/wrong way , being new to coldfusion it has really confuse me, i have all the query ready , just to create this files is what im debating on what is the best way to do it

Comment: It might be worth your while to step away from your code and describe what you are attempting in prose and/or a flowchart.  Then look at what code is available to help you accomplish that objective.

Comment: If you just want to have link for downloading txt file and you try to automate generation of this file and then add the href to point directly to this txt file, well you are over complicating. Please explain what is the purpose of your txt file ?

Answer (score 3):

simple, just create a variables for the file name containing the timestamp and use that for the file attribute of cffile:

```
<cfset currentTime = now()>
<cfset fileName = "newsletter-#DateFormat(currentTime, 'yyyyddmm')#_#TimeFormat(currentTime, 'HHmmss')#.txt">
<cfset fullFilePath = expandPath('./#fileName#')>

<cffile action="write" file="#fullFilePath#" output="#YOUR_CONTENT_VARIABLE#">
```